# insert dynamic content in image swiper

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, swipe

I'm using an image swiper in javascript and i'm trying to pupulate it via ajax request, to load content dynamically.

This is my script, working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ywn1w7fn/2/

But it's not working if i try to populate it via ajax request:

```
var output = $('#swippy');
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/images/images_to_swiper.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var landmark = '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://mywebsite.com//images/'+item.img+'" style="width:100%;"></img></div>';           
                output.append(landmark);

            }); 

        },
        error: function(){
            $( "#popupDialog" ).popup( "open" )
        }
    });
```

my php page returns a json encoded string like this:

```
([{"id":"19","img":"image1.png","posizione":"1"},{"id":"11","img":"anotherimage.jpg","posizione":"6"}]);
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to be wrong in your code though you would like to initialize swiper in the ajax success function.

```
Your code should look like this 

var output = $('#swippy');
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/images/images_to_swiper.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var landmark = '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://mywebsite.com//images/'+item.img+'" style="width:100%;"></img></div>';           
                output.append(landmark);

            }); 

            var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',
            {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                paginationClickable: true,
                autoplay: 2500,
                autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
                preloadImages: false
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            $( "#popupDialog" ).popup( "open" )
        }
    });
```

Hoping this will work for you cheers!